# Correct Pronounciation of "XPath"

Tags: xpath

As a non-native english speaker i am not sure, how to pronounce "XPath" correctly (XPath in context of DOM, when you want to locate an Element for example).

is it pronounced "cross-path" or literally like "x-path"?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jP4YlT9Ex_s

Comment: There's no officially correct pronuncation, but if you go to an XML conference, I think you'll hear everyone saying ex-path. (Now, if you want to know how EXPath is pronounced, you'll get more variation, but it's most likely to be ee-ex-path, just to distinguish it).

Answer (score 3):

XPath is pronounced as the letter X ( *ĕks* ) followed by the word Path ( *păth* ):

- : [audio example](https://forvo.com/search/xpath/)

Comment: iks-păth might be the only other contender, right?

Comment: No, there simply is no other contender.  I've never heard any other pronunciation in over two decades of interacting with colleagues and clients in the XML world.

Answer (score 3):

The [XPath 3.1 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/) doesn't appear to mention pronunciation, so the official answer is likely to be "however you like".

However, it should be noted that the name expands to "XML Path Language", and the X in "XML" in turn stands for "Extensible" (yes, that ought to make it "EML", but "X" looks fancier, so gets used in acronyms a lot...). So, while "X" is sometimes used to represent "cross", or "trans" (e.g. "xfer", "xmit"), or other things, none of those apply here.

Meanwhile, some abbreviations are pronounced as though they were words, and "X" in those can sometimes be pronounced like "Z", as in "XUL", which [references a character in Ghostbusters called "Zuul"](https://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul). However, "XP" is not a natural consonant combination in English, nor is the sound combination "ZP", so it's unlikely anyone would do so in this case.

Most people would therefore read it out like "ex-path".